# Gaussian Process posterior distribution

Tags: r, gaussian-process, posterior, mgcv

I'm trying to find a way to get the posterior covariance function for a `mgcv::gam` fit. Assuming I have a simple model `y ~ s(x)`, how do I find the posterior? Do I simulate and calculate covariances? Do I use some version of the code below?

Will appreciate any pointers!

```
# Gaussian process posterior
def GP(X1, y1, X2, kernel_func):
    """
    Calculate the posterior mean and covariance matrix for y2
    based on the corresponding input X2, the observations (y1, X1), 
    and the prior kernel function.
    """
    # Kernel of the observations
    Σ11 = kernel_func(X1, X1)
    # Kernel of observations vs to-predict
    Σ12 = kernel_func(X1, X2)
    # Solve
    solved = scipy.linalg.solve(Σ11, Σ12, assume_a='pos').T
    # Compute posterior mean
    μ2 = solved @ y1
    # Compute the posterior covariance
    Σ22 = kernel_func(X2, X2)
    Σ2 = Σ22 - (solved @ Σ12)
    return μ2, Σ2  # mean, covariance
```

[source](https://peterroelants.github.io/posts/gaussian-process-tutorial)

Comment: 0. Welcome to CV.SE. 1. You seem to have marked this as an R question but you have linked and pasted Python code. 2. If you are particularly focused on `gam` objects have you tried [`gam.mh`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/mgcv/html/gam.mh.html)? How doesn't it fit your use case?